# Three.JS Shadow to object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to add `castShadow` and `receiveShadow` on a object. But what do I wrong with the following code?...

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath("objects/Tree/");
mtlLoader.load("tree.mtl", function(materials) {
    materials.preload();
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.setPath("objects/Tree/");
    objLoader.load("tree.obj", function(gate) {

        var positionX = 0;
        var positionY = 4;
        var positionZ = 0;

        gate.position.x = positionX;
        gate.position.y = positionY;
        gate.position.z = positionZ;
        gate.scale.x = 2
        gate.scale.y = 2;
        gate.scale.z = 2;
        scene.add(gate);

        gate.castShadow = true;
        gate.receiveShadow = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Casting shadows requires that you setup your lights properly, and set castShadows on them as well. You also need to enable shadowMap on the renderer, and set the desired shadowMap type. Without your full code, there is no way for us to check if you made any errors there. Perhaps you can setup a fiddle?

Comment: I have. When I do it without the MTLoader and OBJLoader it works fine.. sorry for not saying that in my post. It must be something with the loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to traverse through the child and then set castShadow as given below.

```
gate.traverse( function ( child ) {
    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
      child.castShadow = true;
    }
});
```

Here is the working sample http://jsfiddle.net/4Txgp/703/

I think really it should be helpful