# THREE.OBJLoader cast a shadow?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make object cast and receive a shadow,

there is a light source in the scene THREE.SpotLight

here is my code for MTLLoader() and OBJLoader()

```
        var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('assets/');
        mtlLoader.setPath('assets/');
        mtlLoader.load('komoda.mtl', function (materials) {
            materials.preload();
             materials.materials.lambert2SG.map.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
             materials.materials.lambert2SG.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

             materials.materials.lambert3SG.map.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
             materials.materials.lambert3SG.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath('assets/');
            objLoader.load('komoda.obj', function (object) {
                object.castShadow = true;
                object.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add(object);
            });
        });
```

full js code: https://a3d.joladev2.com/webgl2/webgl-attempt.js

and here is online example: https://a3d.joladev2.com/webgl2/index.html

Thank you

EDIT: i have added jsfiddle, but not possible to load materials on jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/fcb9qoco/23/

Thanks

EDIT 2: Resolved - there where 2 problems, one is with spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 500;

the correct value was 10, so spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 10;

thank you @gaitat

Second one was plane object did not have receiveShadow = true;

now it has, thank you @Jim Tang

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399613/three-js-shadow-to-object/

Comment: @WestLangley tried that, does not work.

Comment: can you create a fiddle to try things ?

Comment: @gaitat i have set up fiddle, material is not loading on fiddle.

Comment: you need to change your `spotLight.shadow.camera.near` to a smaller value like 10.

Comment: @gaitat that was it! Thank you so much, do there where 2 problems with it, one is plane didnt have receiveShadow on it, and second one was what you answered, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The online example dose not run on my chrome, so I can not tell, but in my 'Three.js Inspector' debug tab shown the hierarchy:

```
Scene
 +- SpotLight
 +- Group
  |- plane  <-- check this Mesh object receiveShadow property
  |- komoda
```

Comment: Thanks but when i set receiveShadow = true; on plane i get a warning see screenshot https://ibb.co/m1u9MS , pls try opening demo again

Comment: @Avi sorry, I can not find this error in my three.js library, my version is 89, and yours is 76, better using the latest release version.

Comment: there where 2 problems with this, so receiveShadow = true; on plane which was your answer, and the other one was  spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 500; the correct is  spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 10; Thank you so much

Comment: @Avi Ah right! So the spot light underlying camera cuts the scene objects off... You can use a CameraHelper on this camera to debug this.